# Kindle (client) for Mac – is there text search or highlighting/notes?

Tags: macos, kindle

Just so we're clear, I am talking about the client/software version here, i.e. the one that you install on your Mac or PC, not the device.

The Kindle client was recently released for the Mac. I downloaded it and bought a couple of Kindle-edition books to view on this client.

Astonishingly, two features I consider to be more or less essential to any ebook reader are missing in the Kindle client, either that, or I can't find them:

1. **text searching**;
2. **highlighting text**.

First, does anyone know how to access the **search** feature? I'm aware of the "Go To" button at the top middle of the reader window--the options in that menu when you click the button are: "Cover", "Table of Contents", "Beginning" and "Location."  "Location" requires that you type in an integer (but it doesn't correspond to page number--e.g., typing "167" brought me to the table of contents), not a search term.

Second, there's a button on the upper right-hand corner of the window "Show Notes and Marks". Yet I can't find any way to highlight text.  The only kind of "note" or "mark" I have been able to record is to "bookmark" a page by clicking the "bookmark" button also at the top of the window.

Comment: Please consider a question title that does more than specify the product about which you have a question.

Answer (score 2):

You can search on Kindle for Mac! I know this is an old question and I might have a more recent version of Kindle for Mac.

To search for text within your book, in the menu bar, select the full screen option (looks like an "X").  You should then see several icons.  Select the search (magnifying glass). And you can search text!

From [Amazon help](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_macuse_search?nodeId=200443830#search):

> Search for any term or phrase as you read by clicking on any word or
>   clicking and dragging over a passage. Once you've selected text, a
>   pop-up box gives you the option to Highlight, Highlight & Add Note or
>   Search. Select Search to find all locations within the text where this
>   word or phrase appears. Click on the location to turn to that location
>   with the text. Click on "You were here" to return to the last page
>   read.
>
> You can also search by typing in the search field with the magnifying
>   glass on the top right of the application window. Hit the Return
>   button on your keyboard or click on the magnifying glass to begin
>   searching.

Comment: Yes it seems to be added now. Thanks for your helpful answer and welcome to Super User!

Answer (score 1):

From Amazon: [Highlights and Notes](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_macland_uread?nodeId=200443830&#read)

> Click on any word or click and drag over a passage to create a
>   highlight or add a note within a book. Once you've selected text, a
>   pop-up box gives you the option to Highlight, Highlight & Add Note or
>   Search.
>
> [image]
>
> - Choose Highlight to highlight the selected text in yellow.  *
>     Choose Highlight & Add Note to record your thoughts on the selected
>     text by typing your note in the Add Note field.   * The Note icon
>     [insert icon] indicates every note within a book. Click on the Note
>     icon to open a list of All Notes & Marks.
>
> All Notes & Marks and their locations are listed on the right side of
>   the application window. Use the drop down at the top of the list to
>   display either All Notes & Marks, Notes Only, Highlights Only, or
>   Bookmarks Only. Click the "X" to the left of this drop down menu to
>   close the window.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Amazon's Kindle for Mac FAQ](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200438360/ref=kcp_mac_menu), there is no search feature in Kindle for Mac, nor the ability to add notes or highlights.  They do say 'yet', so there's hope for the future.

The "Location" is like page numbers, but for Kindle books.  That number is guaranteed to be the same place in the book no matter what your font setting is or what device you're reading it on.